# div doesn't act on firefox/ie like on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, incompatibility

Could anybody tell me please why does this loading image displays fine in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer or Firefox?
It should just float normally over the page but Firefox and IE seems to put it at the start of the page.

Website: http://thc-racing.ucoz.com/

HTML:

```
<div id="preload">Loading page... <img src="/design/loading.gif" /></div>
```

CSS:

```
div#preload {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 50px;
    background-image: url('http://thc-racing.ucoz.com/design/loading-bg.png');
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #d7d7d7;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    align: right;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: try top, left for positioning instead of bottom, right.

Comment: What is `align: right;`? Do you mean `text-align: right;`?

Comment: Wilson Biggs doesn't really mean anything, my mistake

Comment: palerdot doesn't work, still up there

Comment: Not sure, but the loading image displays in all those three browsers just the same (in the top left corner)

Comment: `align: right` is not valid CSS. Do you mean `text-align: right`?

Comment: I think this is happening because your `div` is before the opening `html` tag. You should place it within the `body` tag. There seem to be a lot of problems in your website. You have more HTML that is not inside the `html` / `body` tag. That is causing problems.

Comment: putvande same result everywhere i put it, doesn't have the exppected result

Comment: Where does it need to go? Vertically and horizontally centered?

Comment: putvande, here is a screenshot with how it should look like http://thc-racing.ucoz.com/problem_ss.jpg

Comment: Well, I would start by putting the HTML in the body tag. If you do that it should work.

Comment: putvande same result, works in chrome, it doesn't in ff/ie, you can check it now, it is in body

Comment: looks like i found the problem (i guess), the css does not provide the necesary code for the div, in chrome it does but not in ff/ic, adding the css with style="" works everywhere. anybody knows why isn't it reading the css code?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the way (probably) firefox and internet explorer understand the div, I had to replace the div with table, because they failed to read the CSS propely, so here is the code:

HTML:

```
<table id="preload"><tbody><tr><td style="padding:8px;">Loading page... </td><td style="padding:8px;"><img src="/design/loading.gif" /></td></tr></tbody><table>
```

CSS:

```
#preload { border-collapse: separate !important; position:absolute; bottom:40px; right:50px; font-weight:bold; background-image:url('/design/loading-bg.png'); border-radius:5px; border-style: solid; border-color:#d7d7d7; border-width: 1px; border-spacing: 0; }
```

everything works perfect now, thanks everybody for help